# I can't use Javascript in Dreamweaver

Tags: javascript, dreamweaver

My Javascript wont activate on dreamweaver. I attached it and everything but when i try to call it with script tags it does not appear on my live preview. i have it attached by this code

```
<script src="file:///C:/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Untitled-2.js" type="text/script"></script>
```

If someone could please help that would be awesome! :D

Comment: Live mode runs Your code in some virtual webserver and it cannot get local js file. Since browser may block resource from sharing (CORS). Think about putting js file to relative to html file and defining relative url to js file. Create `js` folder near to html file and put js file there and in Your html file define `src="js/Untitled-2.js"`

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that is the issue at hand. Html and Css work fine.

Comment: give it a try :D  put Your assets and urls to be relative to each other. js is not css and not html - for browser it's more dangerous thing when it's from different resource.

Comment: Worked after all! I thought I had them all relative but aparently not! Thanks Man!

Answer (score 1):

Live mode runs Your code in some virtual webserver and it cannot get local js file. Since browser may block resource from sharing (CORS). Think about putting js file to relative to html file and defining relative url to js file. Create js folder near to html file and put js file there and in Your html file define src="js/Untitled-2.js" – num8er 12 mins ago

Thanks Num8er

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it is best practice to keep all files relative to the project. This means setting up a project folder and keeping files organised in sub-folders.

Consider this project structure:

- Project folder

  - **CSS folder**

    - style.css
  - **Javascript folder**

    - script.js
  - **Images folder**

    - image.jpg
  - index.html

The sub-folders are directly children of the project folder, and inside each folder is the corresponding files.
The html file is also a direct child of the project folder (it's not in any other folder).

This means all the related files are relative to the html file.

So in your html file, you can link up these files easier.

```
<link href="CSS/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="Javascript/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<img src="Images/image.jpg">
```

As you can see all the files are linked without a full path, this is called **relative linking. Absolute linking** is the opposite in which you specify the full path, such like you are doing at the moment:

```
<script src="file:///C:/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Untitled-2.js" type="text/script"></script>
```

This is good in certain places, however you should always try to aim for relative linking. If you follow this, you shouldn't have any more problems.