# My link opens the html file, but in a deconfigurated way

Tags: html, css, web

Im using this code in the html file:

```html
   <li><a href="ACASE.html" class="ativo">A Case</a></li>
   <li><a href="Calçados.html" class="fade">Calçados</a></li>
   <li><a href="EPIs.html" class="fade">EPIs</a></li>
   <li><a href="Orçamento.html" class="fade">Orçamento</a></li>
   <li><a href="Contato.html" class="fade">Contato</a></li>
```

But in the website when I click in those links they open the html file without the formatting from the css file. For all the hmtl files I used the same css. file, within specification to each one. At the Dreamweaver everything seems perfect and ready to go.

Someone have any idea of what I can do to all pages of the website looks like the css structure? Ps: All html have this code:

```html
 <link rel='stylesheet' id='html5blank-css'  href='C:\Users\X\Documents\mariana\MERCADO\CASE\Site\main.css' media='all' />
```

Thank you already!

Comment: I translated, thanks!

Comment: Looks like a path issue if the CSS is not applying. The "website" cannot access directories on your PC.

Comment: But all the files are in the FPT and the index page also uses the css file, but is working pefectly. Just the linked pages arent.

Comment: I have no idea what FPT is....but I'd still suggest this is path issue.

Comment: I suggest to open the console of the developer tools (`Ctrl+Shift+I` for Firefox, Chrome and Edge) and see if it tells you the reason why the CSS file cannot be loaded. I suppose it's some security issue, either the "same-origin-policy" or the "access to local files" that is forbidden.

Comment: Use relative path to your CSS and make sure, the file is placed on the specified path.

Answer (score 0):

This to me is a path related issue... Please read my detailed answer to another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49155568/2358222).

Dreamweaver requires you to set up a project folder to store all your files in. Doing so, when linking to the files, you specify the paths as relative; as in relative path to the file linking to it. To make things clear and easy for Dreamweaver to understand, you need to use this method of linking.

Instead  of:

```
C:\Users\X\Documents\mariana\MERCADO\CASE\Site\main.css
```

The relative path, if the css file is in the same folder as the html, should be:

```
main.css
```